# angular4 css / js differs when I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-ui-router

When I load a page with this kind of script :

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/report-result/'+report.id);
```

It seems that all the css is not loaded, and the js too.
For example, my bootstrap popover are not loaded, some fields are misplaced.
While I load the page directly with the url or if I refresh the page, all is allright.
Do you have an idea?

Comment: do you use the same report id when refreshing or going to the page directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the way of navigate to something like this:

`this.router.navigate(['report-result', report.id]);`

Remember the routes are absolute, so if your are trying to access to localhost/parentRoute/report-result/report. The you have to do it like this:

`this.router.navigate(['parentRoute', 'report-result', report.id]);`

Or make it to be relative to the parentRoute like this:

`this.router.navigate(['report-result', report.id], {relativeTo:'/parentReport'});`